# could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier on Deferent ViewController

Tags: swift, identifier

**I have set the Identifier On On Deferent View Controller but it showing me that I must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'  **

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if collectionView == self.secondCollectionView {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.mainText.text = Imgname[indexPath.item]
        cell.mainImageView.image = mainImg[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "secondCell", for: indexPath) as! SecondCollectionViewCell
        cell.secondText.text = Imgname[indexPath.item]
        cell.secondImage.image = mainImg[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
}
```

[IdentiFier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV3db.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
var cell: UICollectionViewCell!

if .....{

     cell = 

} else {

     cell =

}

return cell
```

need to write this style of code in function